# How can I have my flask-app run on my sites subdomain?

Tags: python, flask, namecheap

For example, I want to run flask-app on http://api.domain.com . However, I have no idea how to do this and the flask documentation serves no help. I am using a shared namecheap web server via SSH to run python. I have ports 8080, 8181 and 8282 open.

Server-sided code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'domain.com'

@app.route('/status')
def status():
   return 'Status : Online'

bp = Blueprint('subdomain', __name__, subdomain="api")

app.register_blueprint(bp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host=app.config["SERVER_NAME"],port=8181,debug=True)
```

When I visit http://www.api.domain.com/status , it returns a 404 error. 
Nothing displays on the SSH console.

Any help if very much appreciated.

Comment: This is more of a question for setting up your webserver.  You would want to ask a question related to webserver config.  Im not sure if you are using Apache, Nginx, lighttpd, etc.  Each are done differently.

Comment: @Fallenreaper My web hosting is hosted by namecheap along with my domain. I edited my code above to reflect this.

Comment: you need to also set the port your server is using:

 http://www.api.domain.com:8081/status

Comment: I did that. I got a 404.

Comment: first things first: can you get to your server by IP, with the proper port?
DNS is another issue you may need to sort out, but first is your server running? Setting a URL as server host doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: api.domain.com is accessible. The flask-app won't run on the subdomain correctly.

Comment: api.domain.com/status is supposed to return "Online". However, when I go to that in my browser, it returns the link as a 404. Usually when the flask-app returns a 404 an error is displayed on console. This is not the case. This is evidence that the flask-app isnt actually running on the subdomain. I have no idea where its running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first:

http (i.e. a web server without a SSL certificate) is insecure. You should set up a certificate and always use port 443 to the outside.

Then, on namecheap, you need to define a CNAME entry to point to the subdomain.

In Namecheap, click domain -> Manage, then Advanced DNS

Create a new record, select CNAME as the Type, and enter the subdomain name (just the top level) as the HOST, then the IP where you server is as the value (TTL (time to live) is the time it takes to change when you want to change it next time, 1, 10min is useful to debug stuff, but DNS may not honor that anyways...)

Wait a few minutes, and you should be able to reach your server at the subdomain name.

Now, if you use the same IP as a webserver for example, but a different port, that is basically not gonna do what you want. The DNS will forward subdomain traffic to your (same) server IP, so if your webserver is on port 443, you will also reach it with https://api.domain.com. If your API uses port 8080 or 8081, you will need to always specify the port to actually reach the API server at the subdomain (i.e api.domain.com:8080 ).

The DNS merely forwards the subdomain name to the IP you tell it to.

Comment: Im doing this through cPanel. The subdomain already has an A record which points to the server's IP.

Comment: first make sure you can reach the server by IP. Then troubleshoot DNS issues.

Comment: You can reach the server by doing api.domain.com . However, the flask app is not running on the subdomain correctly. Pls help.

Comment: what does it mean 'i can reach the server by doing api.domain.com'? 
if you can reach the server, it is running. if you can't it is not.

Comment: can you reach your app server on the port it is running? if not, can you reach it with the IP directly?

Comment: The subdomain is reachable. The flask app wont run on the subdomain correctly.

Comment: OK, I don't think i'm being clear here: what does that mean: 'it's reachable'? 
if the server is not running, it won't respond. if it responds, it is reachable, and it is running So you're not making sense here.

Comment: The api.domain.com is valid. The flask app that's supposed to run on api.domain.com is not actually run on that subdomain. Please read. Thanks.

Comment: Look, tell me what you tried, and what command you use, or whatever, but don't keep repeating the same thing. it does not help. Did you try reaching the server by IP, with the port your defined for it?

Comment: api.domain.com/status is supposed to return "Online". However, when I go to that in my browser, it returns the link as a 404. Usually when the flask-app returns a 404 an error is displayed on console. This is not the case. This is evidence that the flask-app isnt actually running on the subdomain. I have no idea where its running.

Comment: if you have a web server on the same IP, that is what is responding. you are not using the port that you say your api server is running on, so what is responding with a 404 is the web server.

Comment: so try <your_server_ip_here>:8081/status and see if anything responds.

Comment: It never displayed anything. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: if you don't have logs, then it's probably not going where you think it is.

Comment: your host='domain.com' doesn't seem right. the host should be 0.0.0.0 for an externally visible app.

Comment: what else is running on that same server, if anything?

Comment: is it a dedicated IP or shared IP?

Comment: I set my host to the server's IP address. Nothing is running on the server. Mind you, the server is a web server.

Comment: Shared IP web server.

Comment: and when you start your app, what does the server say? it should prompt with the IP/port it's using

Comment: you need to break things down: if you are ssh'ing into the box, then you should be able to check if the server responds on localhost:8081/status with curl or something

Comment: if that works, then you need to figure how namecheap routes traffic to your server; they likely route your domain on ports 80, 443 and that's it, and you need to configure somewhere what that maps to on yoru server.

Comment: How do they route their servers?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the tornado in Python. I already answered this question and it's working fine

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(int(5000),address="ip_address_of_your_server_machine")
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Now you can access this page like `www.example.com:5000`

Answer (score 0):

Actually Flask is not meant to run a server by itself, it's only for debugging, if you want to run an web app you should run behind a Apache or Nginx with some wsgi, here is an simple example on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04